# Using scanner class I am not able to write text on console using IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner, user-input

Issue: Using scanner class I am not able to write text on console using IntelliJ IDE.
Output: My program keeps running and I need terminate it manually.

Project Structure: Maven
Additional Info: Using TetNG

Below file is created under SRC folder.
BasicPrograms.Java

```
public class BasicPrograms { 
public void takeInpFrmUser() {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("User has entered= " + num);
        sc.close();


    }
}
```

Below file is created under TEST folder.
UserInput.Java

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class UserInput {
    BasicPrograms basicObj;

    @BeforeClass
    public void createObj() {
        basicObj = new BasicPrograms();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyUserInput() {
        basicObj.takeInpFrmUser();
    }

}
```

I am a beginner any trying to learn java by myself. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much :)

What I have tried: Referred java doc

```
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
```

What I expected: I should be able to write the integer text on console.
But my program keeps running and I need to terminate it manually.

Please refer the below image of output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line:

> `sc.close();`

Do not close a `Scanner` based on `System.in`. You are terminating your access to the console. That access cannot be restored.

Otherwise, your code is good. See your [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Yvj1Un).

Comment: Thank you sir for your prompt response but  sir I am still facing the same issue.
On console when I hit "Enter" It say that "This view is read only".

Comment: @Dhaval Then you have other issues not disclosed here. Follow the link to Ideone.com. I copy-pasted your code, unchanged. Works perfectly well.

Comment: Yes. I have checked it. No worries. I will try to find the answer will add here. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0):

first, open IDE (`help -> edit custom VM options`),

then input next code `-Deditable.java.test.console=true` and `restart IDE`.

for example:

[image]
[image: example]